# Get Clicked <li> from <ul onclick>

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

As a relative beginner with JS, I am struggling to try and find a solution to this.

I need to find out which line of an unordered list was clicked

```
<ul onclick="alert(this.clicked.line.id);">
  <li id=l1>Line 1</li>
  <li id=l2>Line 2</li>
  <li id=l3>Line 3</li>
</ul>
```

I don't really want to add a onclick event to each individual line, I'm sure there must be a way ??

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the onclick event, and examining the this.clicked object?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `event.target` for this:

**JS:**

```
// IE does not know about the target attribute. It looks for srcElement
// This function will get the event target in a browser-compatible way
function getEventTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement; 
}

var ul = document.getElementById('test');
ul.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = getEventTarget(event);
    alert(target.innerHTML);
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="test">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/2dEFg/5/

*Please note that this is a very basic example and you will likely encounter some problems when you delegate events to elements containing more than one level. When this happens, you will have to traverse the DOM tree upwards to find the containing element.*

Comment: +1 The key here is taking the Javascript out of the HTML attribute.

Comment: This is correct as long as there are no other elemens in the li's. When you have <li><strong>Item 1</strong></li> than event.target will be the strong element (in that case you have to check the parents).

Comment: is it also possible to add all mouse events to an element and then determine in the handler function what event it was ??

Comment: @crankshaft nope, you will have to bind each event manually (and this makes your code a lot more understandable as well)

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work in IE, I get the error: Error: 'target' is null or not an object

Comment: @cranckshaft IE uses event.srcElement. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: hi can you explain the js used above i mean what we are doing in this js technically ul.Onclick =function....i am new in js and i know basic js

Answer (score 3):

The object which was actually clicked is

```
event.target
```

inside the `onclick` callback. What you are trying to do is a good idea, and it is known as [event delegation](http://www.cherny.com/webdev/70/javascript-event-delegation-and-event-hanlders).

http://jsfiddle.net/VhfEh/

Comment: Easy solution that works if you don't care about IE8.

Answer (score 3):

You can use event.target for this:

Did not seem to be working so I made small change seems to be working now.

```
var ul = document.getElementById('test');
ul.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    alert(event.target.innerHTML);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

//The simplest way to do this might be to append a query parameter to your links:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="Line 1">Line 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="Line 2">Line 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="Line 3">Line 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want exact value of element then following code can work.Use innerText except innerHTML
JS:

```
function getEventTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement; 
}

var ul = document.getElementById('test');
    ul.onclick = function(event) {
var target = getEventTarget(event);
    alert(target.innerText);
};
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="test">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
```

Comment: The answer is 'window.event.target'.  Thank you good sir.